# How to call methods using schedule module in python?

Tags: python, oop, schedule

we can call a simple function using schedule like this

```
import schedule
def wake_up():
    print("Wake Up! It's 8:00")
schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(wake_up)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

but when im creating a class and calling a method

```
import schedule
class Alarm():
    def wake_up(self):
        print("Wake Up!")
alarm=Alarm()
schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(alarm.wake_up())
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

i get

```
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `alarm.wake_up()` with `alarm.wake_up`.

When you add the parenthesis, you actually call and execute the method `wake_up`. However, when you just do `alarm.wake_up`, it creates a reference to that method instead, which is what the schedule module wants.

Change is on line 7:

```
import schedule
class Alarm():
    def wake_up(self):
        print("Wake Up!")

alarm=Alarm()
schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(alarm.wake_up)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```